# leaflet.draw with CartoDB

Tags: gis, leaflet, cartodb

I am new to leaflet.js and CartoDB.js.  What I am trying to do is create a editable webmap, sourcing (and writing) data to my CartoDB SQL tables.  I can render the map from CartoDB, but when I add the links to leaflet.js my map layers disappear.  This [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bretwhiteley/sryt14m0/1/) shows this.  If you comment out lines 5 and 6, it works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add the Leaflet library's javascript and stylesheet when using CartoDB, just include the Leaflet Draw's assets, enable the `drawControl` option in the options of `L.Map` and you're good to go:

Assets:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/leaflet.draw.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
```

Map:

```
new L.Map('cartodb-map', { 
    center: [40,-98],
    zoom: 4,
    drawControl: true
});
```

Here's a fork of your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qnzqtgy7/

Comment: Thanks iH8 - that did the trick... I now need to figure out how to write the edits back to the CartoDB table, I am following this thread (http://blog.cartodb.com/read-and-write-to-cartodb-with-the-leaflet-draw-plugin/) - I think it'll get me there